# Scrolling layout in automatic test

Tags: android, python, selenium, appium

I develop automatic test in Selenium appium using python.
I need scroll item list, but I don't have any idea, how to do it.
I try:

```
scrollLayout = android.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("android.widget.RelativeLayout")
params = {"element": scrollLayout[0].id, "text": SEARCH_STRING}
self.android.driver.execute_script("mobile: scrollTo", params)
```

but, it's not working.
What I should do?

Answer (score 4):

```
WebElement list = driver.findElement(By.id("id of your list"));

     HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
     scrollObject.put("text", "name to search");
     scrollObject.put("element",( (RemoteWebElement) list).getId());
     driver.executeScript("mobile: scrollTo", scrollObject);
     if(scrollObject.containsValue("string to search"))
     {
        System.out.println("Found");
        List<WebElement> list_user = list.findElements(By.id("id of the text view"));
        for (WebElement component : list_user) {
           System.out.println(component.getText());
           if (component.getText().contains("string to search")) {
                component.click();
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not equal");
            }
     }
     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("Not Found");
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code it will work. This is java code change it accordingly to python

```
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("android:id/select_dialog_listview"));
            HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
            scrollObject.put("text", "The text name you need to scroll to");
            scrollObject.put("element",( (RemoteWebElement) element).getId());
            driver.executeScript("mobile: scrollTo", scrollObject);
```